# I am trying to understand implementation of observable,I visualize it in this way ,am i correct?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, stream, rxjs, subject

I tried to learn internal implementation of observables.This flow of code is according to my understanding ,Am going in right direction?

```
function OBSERVABLE(callback){
this.subscribe=callback.bind(this);

};
var obs$=new OBSERVABLE(function(observer){
this.next=observer.next;

});
obs$.subscribe({next:function(e){
console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: I think this fits better on code-review SE. as there's no specific problem here.

Comment: No,this is not a code.This is my understanding that i wrote in code form,so that other people could also figure out ,and share their views

Comment: There are articles and videos on "creating your own rxjs". E.g. ["A simple Observable implementation"](https://medium.com/@fknussel/a-simple-observable-implementation-c9c809c89c69) by Federico Knüssel